# Как можно сделать фильтрацию слов?

Tags: javascript

На вход поступает слово,например:

```
var name = "космос";
```

И есть нужное слово:

```
var result = "космос";
```

Нужно если `name == result` возвращать true,но учитывать подобные варианты:
 `name = "козмос/космоз/космас"` и тд.
Как это можно примерно сделать?
Т.е нужно чтобы при голосовом наборе убрать подобные опечатки.

Comment: Ничего себе задачка) Если есть словарь возможных слов и допустимое количество ошибочных букв, то с какойто вероятностью вы можете вычислять совпадения. Но при нескольких похожих словах в словаре возможны ложные срабатывания. В общем это непростая задача. Если нужен резульзат близкий к 99% на большом словаре, то вам скорее нужна нейронка, чтоб семантически анализировала текст)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
function equals(word1, word2) {
                var ERR_LEVEL = 1;
                var arrWord1 = word1.split('');
                var arrWord2 = word2.split('');
                if (arrWord1.length !== arrWord2.length) {
                    return false;
                }

                var currentErrorLevel = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrWord1.length; i++) {
                    arrWord1[i] !== arrWord2[i] && currentErrorLevel++;

                }
                return currentErrorLevel <= ERR_LEVEL;  
            }
```

Здесь ERR_LEVEL - уровень равенства, в данном случае возможно отличие в одной букве

Comment: Во,спасибо большое)